# Alignment of image captions does not begin from left

Tags: floats, captions, article, wide-image

I am using the Elsevier Latex template to prepare a journal article (two-column).

With this template, the captions of my figures that span both columns always begin at the center.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel,stackengine}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}


%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Fourier journal}
\shortauthors{Joshitha. R et~al.}


\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{\footnotesize }
    \end{subfigure} 
   \begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{\footnotesize }
    \end{subfigure} 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{\footnotesize}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{\footnotesize}
    \end{subfigure}\vspace{3pt}

\caption{\footnotesize (\textbf{a}) The extracted 13$\times$13 views of  \textit{Fountain-Vincent2}; central view of (\textbf{b}) \textit{Bikes}; (\textbf{c}) \textit{Fountain-Vincent2}; (\textbf{d}) \textit{Stone-Pillars Outside}.}
\label{fig:the dataset}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

What should I do to to correctly begin the captions from the left?

The same code snippet works perfectly well in other templates.

[Zip file of the template used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_68S1oNgV8vHl_F4q5z7YRc6q8deLR-V/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I run your sample file, I don't get the same result. Please make sure that your MWE actually reproduces the error that you get.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered on a fully up-to-date TeX system (specifically: MacTeX2021, `LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1`, `L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>`, `cas-dc 2021/05/11, 2.3`). Please tell us more about your computing setup.

Comment: Also, there appears to be a bug in the cas-dc class file where it expects `\bibsep` to be defined at the beginning of the document but it's not. Apparently it expects the LaTeX file to include `\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}` to run correctly.

Comment: @DonHosek - I encountered that bug as well. :-) Not knowing what package(s) might be needed, I "fixed" the bug by running `\newlength\bibsep` right before `\documentclass`...

Comment: @DonHosek  Thank your for your comments. I have added the complete code snippet and inculded the .bst, .sty, .cls files used in the zip file attached. This might potentially help the debugging. Please have a look ! :)

Comment: @Mico can you please let me know how I can get details of my Latex computing setup?

Comment: @JoshithaR Tools > Clear Auxiliary Files > Compile again and see

Comment: @JoshithaR - MikTeX and TeXLive are two well-known TeX distributions. If your main tex file is called `main.tex`, say, the file name of the log file is called `main.log`. It should be in the directory that contains your main tex file. The first dozen or so lines of the log file should provide plenty of information about the TeX distribution you employ.

Comment: @Mico, I use overleaf online. Here are the details of the Tex distribution:  `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  30 JUN 2021 05:13
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**manuscipt.tex
(/compile/manuscipt.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/compile/cas-dc.cls
Document Class: cas-dc 2020/03/14, 2.1: Formatting class for CAS double column 
articles`

Comment: @Victor I use overleaf, so I cleared the auxillary files by selecting the 'trash' icon at the bottom of 'logs and output files'. On recompiing, there still isn't any change in my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you report in a follow-up comment, Overleaf is currently still using TeXLive2020, the 2020-02-02 version of the LaTeX2e kernel, and `cas-dc` 2020-03-14, version 2.1 of the document class. You may have discovered an unfortunate interaction between LaTeX and the `cas-dc` document class.

Anyway, with TeXLive2021, LaTeX2e kernel 2021-06-01, and `cas-dc` 2021-05-11 v. 2.3, the issue appears to have gone away. You may want to contact the Overleaf help desk -- their LaTeX support staff is top-notch! -- and ask them for help with obtaining the latest version of `cas-dc`. Maybe that'll suffice to get around the alignment problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{%fancyhdr, % I wouldn't use this package with this document class
            graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % it's best to load hyperref last

%\usepackage{amssymb} % don't load packages twice!
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%Author definitions  % not needed for this MWE
%\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
%\tsc{WGM}
%\tsc{QE}
%\tsc{EP}
%\tsc{PMS}
%\tsc{BEC}
%\tsc{DE}

\begin{document}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Fourier journal}
\shortauthors{Joshitha. R et~al.}


\begin{figure*}%[t]  % [t] has no effect on placement of double-wide floats
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={footnotesize,sf}}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure} %\vspace{3pt}

\caption{\footnotesize 
  (a) The extracted 13$\times$13 views of  
      \textit{Fountain-Vincent2}; central view of 
  (b) \textit{Bikes}; 
  (c) \textit{Fountain-Vincent2}; 
  (d) \textit{Stone-Pillars Outside}.}
\label{fig:the dataset}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico ! I did get in touch with them and got a prompt response (AND FIX!). Here's what they said :

 "Thanks for getting in touch. The cas-dc document class has made some changes to how floats are handled; common placement identifiers may actually cause some errors.
If you remove [t!] from your \begin{figure*}, the caption will be centered, with or without new versions of the .cls."   

A simple fix to an issue I have had for days ! Infact even your answer with the [t] commented out brought out the required solution!